# Getting undefined index when retrieving json value of key name having a dot within in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, naming-conventions, undefined-index

My JSON file has this structure:

```js
[
  {
    "n.name": "name1",
    "n.section": ["section1"]
  },
  {
    "n.name": "name2",
    "n.section": ["section2a", "section2b"]
  },
```

I [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/3416774) and having no error:

```php
$input = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/node.json");
$jsonclean = removeBOM($input);
$data = json_decode($jsonclean, true);
echo 'Error code: '. $error; //Error code: 0
```

I want to echo only the values of the `n.name` keys (e.g. `name1 name2 name3...`). However using `echo $data['n.name'];` yields:

> Notice: Undefined index: n.name

According to ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/3416774), this is just a way for PHP to be more secure, and my method should work in theory. I then try:

```php
$value = isset($_POST['n.name']) ? $_POST['n.name'] : '';
$value = !empty($_POST['n.name']) ? $_POST['n.name'] : '';
echo $value;
```

But it prints nothing. I'm not sure if that's the correct way to debug this?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `print_r($data);`?

Comment: @Gregor it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is a array of items, so when you decode it with json_decode, you should iterate over each item and retrieve the key that you want. Example:

```
$json = '[
  {
    "n.name": "name1",
    "n.section": ["section1"]
  },
  {
    "n.name": "name2",
    "n.section": ["section2a", "section2b"]
  }]';

  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  foreach($data as $item) {
      echo $item['n.name'] . "<br>";
  }
```

Output:

```
name1
name2
```

Comment: ah I see. At first I try `$data['n.name']`. What is the difference between `foreach($data as $item)` and `foreach ($data as $key => $val)`?

Comment: You access them like `$data[0]['n.name']`.

Comment: You should use some loop logic to iterate over your array or use $data[0]['n.name'], $data [1]['n.name'] etc but is not a good idea. You need to study about arrays at least.